# Using IntelliJ 2019.3.1 for plugin development for Clion. How to add c++ language support for my plugin project?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, clion, intellij-plugin

I am currently learning about writing plugins for IntelliJ IDEs. I am especially interested in 
developing plugins for CLion. Therefore I would like to add support for c++ to my plugin project.

### My problem:

I read in the documentation how to develop plugins for c++.However the way it is described does not work for me.  IntelliJ cannot resolve the dependency I want to add.

### What I currently know:

**1.** 
[This](https://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics/getting_started/plugin_compatibility.html#modules-specific-to-functionality) part of the documentation explains that plugins may depend on other plugins, 
and how to add dependencies.

> **Plugin dependencies**
>
> Your plugin may depend on classes from other plugins. In this case,
>   plugins can be either bundled, third-party or even your own. For
>   instructions on how to express the dependencies, refer to Plugin
>   Dependencies.
>
> Your plugin should specify which product or products it will be
>   compatible with (all IntelliJ-based IDEs, CLion only, or some subset).
>   **You can do that** by declaring module dependencies with the 
>   tag in plugin.xml (see Plugin Compatibility with IntelliJ Products).

**2.** [This](https://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics/getting_started/plugin_compatibility.html#modules-specific-to-functionality) part of the documentation explains which functionality is in which plugin. Each specific language seems to be a plugin. So developing a plugin which wants to parse c++, will depend on the c++ plugin.

> **Modules Specific to Functionality** More specialized functionality is also delivered via modules and plugins in IntelliJ Platform-based
>   products. For example, the com.intellij.modules.python module supports
>   the Python language-specific functionality. If a plugin uses
>   functionality from this module, such as Python-specific inspections
>   and refactoring, it must declare a dependency on this module.
>
> ...
>
> The following table lists(1) modules or built-in plugins that provide
>   specific functionality, and the products that currently ship with
>   them.

According to the table mentioned above I need to add `<depends>com.intellij.modules.cidr.lang</depends>` as dependency for c++. However when I add this line to my `plugins.xml` file  the cidr.lang part is not recognized.

**3.** In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57538497/gradle-fails-trying-to-build-class-using-psimethod-in-intellij-plugin-project) Stackoverflow question, which is about java plugin development, someone answered that there was recently a change, that one now also has to add the needed plugins to build.gradle. Furthermore there was a change tha java language support is now a buildin plugin.

### My guess what todo

I guess c++ support is now also a buildin plugin? But how can I add it?

So instead of

```
intellij {
    version '2019.2'
    plugins 'java'
}
```

Maybe I need something like this?

```
intellij {
    version '2019.2'
    plugins 'c++' // or maybe cidr??
}
```

---

### Appendix

**My java class:**

```
import com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.AnAction;
import com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.AnActionEvent;
import com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.CommonDataKeys;
import com.intellij.openapi.editor.Editor;
import com.intellij.openapi.ui.Messages;
import com.intellij.psi.PsiElement;
import com.intellij.psi.PsiFile;
import com.intellij.psi.PsiRecursiveElementWalkingVisitor;
//import com.jetbrains.cidr.lang.psi.OCFunctionDefinition; <-- This import does not work 
public class HelloAction extends AnAction {
    public HelloAction() {
        super("Hello");
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(AnActionEvent anActionEvent) {
        Editor editor = anActionEvent.getData(CommonDataKeys.EDITOR);
        PsiFile psiFile = anActionEvent.getData(CommonDataKeys.PSI_FILE);
        if (editor == null || psiFile == null) return;
        int offset = editor.getCaretModel().getOffset();

        final StringBuilder infoBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        PsiElement element = psiFile.findElementAt(offset);
        infoBuilder.append("Element at caret: ").append(element).append("\n");
        Messages.showMessageDialog(anActionEvent.getProject(), infoBuilder.toString(), "PSI Info", null);

        psiFile.accept(new PsiRecursiveElementWalkingVisitor(){
            @Override
            public void visitElement(PsiElement element) {
                super.visitElement(element);
                infoBuilder.append(element.getText()).append("\n");

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void update(AnActionEvent e) {
        Editor editor = e.getData(CommonDataKeys.EDITOR);
        PsiFile psiFile = e.getData(CommonDataKeys.PSI_FILE);
        e.getPresentation().setEnabled(editor != null && psiFile != null);
    }
}
```

**My build.gradle file**

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.jetbrains.intellij' version '0.4.15'
}

group 'org.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}

// See https://github.com/JetBrains/gradle-intellij-plugin/
intellij {
    version 'LATEST-EAP-SNAPSHOT'
    type 'CL'
}
patchPluginXml {
    changeNotes """
      Add change notes here.<br>
      <em>most HTML tags may be used</em>"""
}
```

**My plugin.xml**

```
<idea-plugin>
    <id>org.helloplugin</id>
    <name>Hello Action Project</name>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <vendor email="dummy" url="dummy">dummy</vendor>

    <depends>com.intellij.modules.lang</depends>
    <depends>com.intellij.modules.cidr.lang</depends> // cannot be resolved

    <extensions defaultExtensionNs="com.intellij">
    </extensions>

    <actions>
        <group id="MyPlugin.SampleMenu" text="Greeting" description="Greeting menu">
            <add-to-group group-id="MainMenu" anchor="last"/>
            <action id="Myplugin.Textboxes" class="HelloAction" text="Hello" description="Says hello"/>
        </group>
    </actions>
</idea-plugin>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in the documentation. I just had to reimport the project.

> Exploring Module and Plugin APIs
>
> Once the dependency on a module or plugin is declared in plugin.xml,
>   it’s useful to explore the packages and classes available in that
>   dependency. The section below gives some recommended procedures for
>   discovering what’s available in a module or plugin on which a project
>   depends. These procedures assume a project has the build.gradle and
>   plugin.xml dependencies configured correctly. Exploring APIs as a
>   Consumer
>
> Exploring the available packages and classes in a plugin or module
>   utilizes features in the IntelliJ IDEA IDE.
>
> If the project is not up to date, Reimport the Gradle project as a
>   first step. Reimporting the project will automatically update the
>   dependencies.

So for c++ language support there is no need to add something to build.gradle

**My plugin.xml**

```
<idea-plugin>
    <id>org.helloplugin</id>
    <name>Hello Action Project</name>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <vendor email="dummy" url="dummy">dummy</vendor>

    <depends>com.intellij.modules.platform</depends>
    <depends>com.intellij.modules.lang</depends>
    <depends>com.intellij.modules.cidr.lang</depends>


    <extensions defaultExtensionNs="com.intellij">
    </extensions>

    <actions>
        <group id="MyPlugin.SampleMenu" text="Greeting" description="Greeting menu">
            <add-to-group group-id="MainMenu" anchor="last"/>
            <action id="Myplugin.Textboxes" class="HelloAction" text="Hello" description="Says hello"/>
        </group>
    </actions> </idea-plugin>
```